# How do I loop my Media Player files?

Tags: android, loops, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Basically I have 3 songs, and I want the user to be able to loop back to the first song once the cycle of 3 songs is complete. Why won't this work? It will play all 3 songs, then on the fourth click, no song is played.

```
MediaPlayer song0, song1, song2;
Button play, next;
ArrayList<MediaPlayer> music = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
int track = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     song0 = MediaPlayer.create(TheParty0Activity.this, R.raw.blacksunempire);
     song1 = MediaPlayer.create(TheParty0Activity.this, R.raw.blueskies);
     song2=  MediaPlayer.create(TheParty0Activity.this, R.raw.fuckingnoise);

     music.add(song0);
     music.add(song1);
     music.add(song2);

     play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
     next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

     play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            music.get(track).start();

        }
    });

     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            music.get(track).stop();
            track++;
            if(track == 3)
                track = 0;

            music.get(track).start();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what you exactly you want to do/...???

Comment: you should restart your media player before you start it again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call the function:

[MediaPlayer.setLooping(true|false)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29)

on the mediaplayerObject after you called `MediaPlayer.prepare()`

**Example:**

```
Uri mediaUri = createUri(context, R.raw.media); // Audiofile in raw folder
Mediaplayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setDataSource(context, mediaUri);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.prepare();

mPlayer.setLooping(true);

mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Note that there's no way to set a finite number of loops, and (from my experience) the looping is most definitely not gapless. If preloading the sounds isn't a problem, SoundPool is better at looping.

Comment: Indefinitely until you call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop()

Comment: I think this will loop only one file, and not go through all the files.