# Loop doesn't work when using try and catch on android

Tags: android, loops, try-catch

```
private MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.main);
    player.setLooping(true);
        try {
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    player.stop();
    player = null;}
```

I tried to play some music while the activity is running, it's working very well but the loop is not.
Without the try/catch it works fine but the music starts before the activity is fully loaded.

Can anyone tell me how to make the music run with the 'prepare' function and so the music will loop?

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question? Are you having trouble with `setLooping` or the try catch block?

Comment: Please follow this link , this may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951420/how-do-i-loop-my-media-player-files][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951420/how-do-i-loop-my-media-player-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setLooping(true)` *after* you call `prepare()`